# i want to add footer on all the tabs in my application to show weather

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, footer

i have added footer in tab activity footer is shown in all tabs but  problem is that it comes *over* the *data* so data at bottom is not visible.

here is my code of xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativ_layout"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff8800"

                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" >



               </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" >


                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



        </LinearLayout>



    </TabHost>

    // footer *************************************************
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#F00000"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Fixed Footer"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>    

            //********************************************

</RelativeLayout>








 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



 </FrameLayout>



 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white">




          <RelativeLayout      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/navigationdrawer"


    >



         <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txtemail"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Shivam1692@gmail.com"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

     </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"

            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="TITLE" />

            <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0.3dp"
         />



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

please tell me how to *add* **footer** *below* the *data*.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-header-and-footer-layout-example.html)

Comment: @JoanColmenero i have implemented same e.g but it is coming over data,,

Comment: Can you let us see how your screen look?

Comment: @JoanColmenero i dont have enough reputation to post image.

Comment: Put the link of your image

Comment: @JoanColmenero     here is the link   [link ](http://imgur.com/lJhQnsK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using nested relative layouts, like below

```
<!-- Header -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Header"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Footer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Content -->
<!-- Place your content in this layout-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result: (Borders added for clarity)

[image: Result]

Comment: i wanna add footer on tabs

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereJust add a padding bottom 30dp[android:paddingbottom="30dp"] to the LinearLayout which you have used

Or

Change the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and add android:layout_below="@id/footer"

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativ_layout"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp" >
```